# What is the VB.NET equivalent of this C# Razor syntax?

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In the MVC 3 book by Steven Sanderson on p185 at the bottom, the following expression is used to render the paging links.

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.Paginginfo, x=> Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))
```

What is the VB.NET equivalent? I am stuck on the x url lambda bit.

Comment: Learning MVC3 as a VB.Net developer is really hard - I found there was very little official or community support for it (especially when it first appeared). In the end I found it easier to learn enough C# to follow the C# tutorials - it turned out to be less work than translating every example and tutorial into VB.Net before I could follow it and THEN trying to learn MVC3 from them.  It turned out to be easier than I expected to learn C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.NET the lambda should be equivalent to this:

```
Function(x) Url.Action("List", New With { .Page = x })
```

You can refer to MSDN for more information about VB.NET's:

- [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)
- [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)